# how to remove icon for drawer fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, drawertoggle

I have used 
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
to remove the drawer icon. It worked but it seems the icon still occupies the space as before. Also, there remains a small transparent button that can be used to open the drawer. Can I remove the icon "completely"? Or what's the exact width the icon will occupy so that I can add same margin at right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false)`, this will revert to the  `android.R.attr.homeAsUpIndicator` drawable provided from the theme. Then calling `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)` and `actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);` will hide the indicator.